# I am trying to back fill values in one column from the most recent value in that Column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I am attempting to back-fill a column with the previous information. Like so

```
BizID   Quarter Value
4168    201501  GOLD
4168    201502  NULL
4168    201503  NULL
4168    201504  NULL
4168    201601  REGISTERED
4168    201602  NULL
4168    201603  NULL
4168    201604  NULL
```

What I want

```
BizID   Quarter Value
4168    201501  GOLD
4168    201502  GOLD
4168    201503  GOLD
4168    201504  GOLD
4168    201601  REGISTERED
4168    201602  REGISTERED
4168    201603  REGISTERED
4168    201604  REGISTERED
```

I am operating on Microsoft SQL Server 2014. So the LAG() function does not work, nor does the LAST_VALUE () function. I tried both of these, which resulted in the same ERROR "Function() is not a recognized built-in function name.".

My full code is below. I have created 3 separate tables. The first one [DummyTable] simply lists 8 quarters. The second one [History] brings in the PartnerAttributevalues (these only are populated when a change occurs). And the third [Latest] scours information from records previous to 2014 for the most relevant information and fills in the top row value.

```
SELECT DummyTable.BusinessID
    , DummyTable.Quarter
    , CASE WHEN ((History.PartnerAttributeValue IS NULL) AND (DummyTable.Quarter = 201501)) THEN Latest.PartnerAttributeValue
            ELSE History.PartnerAttributeValue
            END AS PartnerAttributeValue
            FROM 
                (SELECT BizID.BusinessID,Quart.Quarter
                    FROM(
                        (SELECT PPAV.BusinessID
                            FROM Partner_PartnerAttributeValue PPAV
                            WHERE PPAV.BusinessID = 4168
                            GROUP BY PPAV.BusinessID)BizID
                    CROSS JOIN 
                        (SELECT * FROM 
                        (VALUES ('201501', '2015-01-01','2015-03-31')
                              , ('201502', '2015-04-01','2015-06-30')
                              , ('201503', '2015-07-01','2015-09-30')
                              , ('201504', '2015-10-01','2015-12-31')
                              , ('201601', '2016-01-01','2016-03-31')
                              , ('201602', '2016-04-01','2016-06-30')
                              , ('201603', '2016-07-01','2016-09-31')
                              , ('201604', '2016-10-01','2016-12-31')) AS Quarters(Quarter,StartDate,EndDate)) Quart
                        )
                )DummyTable 
            LEFT JOIN
                (SELECT PPAV.BusinessID
                        , (cast(year(PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueStartDate) as char(4)) + '0' + cast(datepart(qq, PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueStartDate) as char(1))) AS Quarter
                        , PAV.PartnerAttributeValue
                    FROM Partner_PartnerAttributeValue PPAV
                    JOIN PartnerAttributeValue PAV
                        ON PAV.PartnerAttributeValueID = PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueID
                    WHERE PAV.PartnerAttributeID = 7
                        AND (PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueID = 22 OR PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueID = 795 OR PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueID = 796)
                        AND PPAV.BusinessID = 4168

                    GROUP BY PPAV.BusinessID
                            , (cast(year(PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueStartDate) as char(4)) + '0' + cast(datepart(qq, PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueStartDate) as char(1)))
                            , PAV.PartnerAttributeValue
                )History
                ON History.BusinessID = DummyTable.BusinessID
                AND History.Quarter = DummyTable.Quarter
            LEFT JOIN 
                (SELECT MAX(PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueStartDate) as MAXDate
                    , PAV.PartnerAttributeValue
                    , PPAV.BusinessID
                    FROM Partner_PartnerAttributeValue PPAV
                    JOIN PartnerAttributeValue PAV
                    ON PAV.PartnerAttributeValueID = PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueID
                    WHERE PAV.PartnerAttributeID = 7
                        AND (PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueID = 22 OR PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueID = 795 OR PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueID = 796)
                        AND (PPAV.BusinessID = 4168)
                        AND((cast(year(PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueStartDate) as char(4)) + '0' + cast(datepart(qq, PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueStartDate) as char(1))) < 201501)
                    GROUP BY PAV.PartnerAttributeValue
                        , PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueStartDate
                        , PPAV.BusinessID
                )Latest
            ON Latest.BusinessID = DummyTable.BusinessID
```

I am trying to figure out a way to back-fill this information most efficiently as possible. The instance I have provided only looks at one instance of this. In the larger build I will be doing this for tens of thousands of Businesses, so efficiency is key.

Thank you for any help and or guidance!

Answer (score 0):

`LAG()` and `LAST_VALUE()` are both supported in SQL Server 2014.  You should check your SQL Server compatibility level (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933794.aspx)).

In any case, SQL Server does not support the `IGNORE NULLS` option for `LAG()`, which would be the easiest way to do this.

Here is another way:

```
select t.BizID, t.Quarter, t.Value, tval.value as new_value
from t outer apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from t2
      where t2.BizID = t.BizId and t2.Value is not null and
            t2.Quarter <= t.Quarter
      order by t2.Quarter desc
     ) tval;
```

This is easy to incorporate into an `update`, if you want to change the data in-place as well.